# Why deleted file in AWS EC2 CentOS is not reducing disk free space?

Tags: linux, disk-space, centos-7, tomcat

I have deleted catalina.out file from tomcat's log folder in **AWS EC2 CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)**. The size of the file was 2.9GB, when I deleted using **rm catalina.out** it is deleted but the disk free space remains same. I am checking with `df -h` command.

Can any one tell me why the disk size is not reduced ? And is there any way to clean it if it is persisted somewhere ? Thanks

Comment: how are you checking the disk size?

Comment: If any process still was writing to the file, it won't actually be freed from the disk until that process releases it.  So you have removed the directory entry for it, but it may not actually be gone until the process is done with it

Comment: You might be able to verify that a process still has it open by running `lsof` and looking for it, you might see something like `catalina.out (deleted)` in the list, which would tell you which process is still holding onto the file

Comment: @JakeGould Sorry, I mean to say Free Space, corrected question. So, any idea how I can remove it permanently ? I am not very good with Linux file system though. Thanks.

Comment: @Sathya I am checking as **df -h**. Edited the question. Thanks.

Comment: @EricRenouf I have deleted that *catalina.out* file and as you know we need this file to see logs I again created using *touch* command and it's size in KB only. That's why I am surprised. Thanks

Comment: @PrabhatSubedi that doesn't change my answer though.  The old file will still exist if a process had it open, so whatever writes to the file probably needs to be restarted before the old space will be freed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49840/discussion-between-prabhat-subedi-and-eric-renouf).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [deleting files but disk space is still full](http://superuser.com/questions/738690/deleting-files-but-disk-space-is-still-full)