# Find out what is consuming diskspace

Tags: linux

I am running a Debian Linux VM.  I have a drive mounted at `/` that appears to be at 99% capacity:

```
>df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       57G   54G  734M  99% /
udev             10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs           2.4G   35M  2.4G   2% /run
tmpfs           5.9G     0  5.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           5.9G     0  5.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           1.2G     0  1.2G   0% /run/user/1000
tmpfs           1.2G     0  1.2G   0% /run/user/0
```

I am trying to use `du` to determine what is taking up so much space.

I'm running:

```
sudo du -ah /
```

It outputs a very long list of files, but ultimately the "total" it displays shows as only `17G`:

```
>sudo du -ah /
... output ommitted
24K /sbin/chcpu
252K    /sbin/e2fsck
0   /sbin/mkdosfs
0   /sbin/init
64K /sbin/mkswap
8.1M    /sbin
17G /
```

So how is it possible that `df -h` is saying that `54G` is used, but running `du` over the root directory shows a total of only `17G`?

Comment: Is Btrfs involved? What's the output of `mount`?

Comment: Mount shows: `/dev/xvda1 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)`

Comment: you might try `du -h -d 1 / | sort -h` and then execute it against the largest size folders which will be on bottom of the output.

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/q/738690/432690), especially where answers mention deleted files in use still taking space. Can you reboot? Does it help (at least temporarily)?